# Macosx, C and embedded lua

Tags: c, lua, osx-leopard

Ok, what we have:

Program written on C which compiling and running without problems in Linux and MacOSX (leopard).
I embedded lua code today. Linux: compiled lua 5.1 from source. Everything works and compiles without any problems. Macos: compiled the same lua 5.1 package.

Linked with --llua.

Started compile and got an error:

CC=gcc-4.0 make

> ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/liblua.a, file is not of required architecture

Also tried reinstall, complete remove and installing from macports. The same.

So is there any fix for that?

Comment: `_Lua_Call` is not a symbol in the Lua C API.

Comment: Cool, but its compiling and its working, the main problem with macos error ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/liblua.a, file is not of required architecture

Comment: If you have compiled and installed Lua from source downloaded from http://www.lua.org this should not happen.

Comment: Yes and also the same error with Lua from macports

Comment: See Luiz's (one of Lua's authors) comment above. Lua's source is pure ANSI C with no external dependencies. It's incredibly easy to build. Rather than lying on a library built by someone else, just build it yourself or add the source to your project. It's beyond trivial on a Unix-like system.

Comment: Thx, i know that. But tried everything. Whats the normal way to link to lua libraries when building program with gcc?

Comment: *For dynamic compile. For static i think its -llua or -llua5.1 depends of what package do you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `"file is not of required architecture"` hints to the fact that you're trying to mix architectures.

Check the architecture of the `/usr/local/lib/liblua.a` and make sure it matches the architecture or the object you're trying to build.

E.g.

We have a i386 object:

```
==== cat fun.c ==== 
#include <stdio.h>
void fun()
{
    printf("%s", "foobar\n");
}
gcc -arch i386 -c fun.c -o fun.o
```

if we try to use it when compiling a x86_64 object (default architecture in Mac OS X):

```
===== cat test.c ==
extern void fun();
int main()
{
    fun();
}
```

we get:

```
$ gcc test.c fun.o
ld: warning: ignoring file fun.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fun", referenced from:
      _main in ccXVCQhG.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I think you are right. But how can i change the arch of liblua.a ? Compile from source?I think I already tried that

Comment: You either recompile liblua.a or recompile your program matching the architecture of liblua.a.

Comment: Did it. Now i have: Undefined symbols: and ld: symbol(s) not found

Comment: So you've solved the architecture mismatch by using i386 both for liblua and your code and you face missing symbol errors. Which are the missing symbols? Are they exported by liblua? **nm /usr/local/lib/liblua.a** will show you the symbols. See the `nm` man page for details.

Comment: Like lhf said this symbols are not symbols in the Lua C API. But on on my Ubuntu its compiling without problems.

Comment: It's likely that somewhere in your source file you have a call to *Lua_Init*. Since there's no such call in the LUA API, you will get an undefined symbol.